# What happens if sparksession is not closed？

Tags: pyspark

1.Does sparksession need to be closed for standard usage?
2.Is it normal for sparksession to stop every time and it takes several seconds to connect again?
3.If sparksession is not stopped, is the resource occupied all the time, there will be a memory leak
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

A Spark application can have only one SparkContext. You don't have to close unless the application is used only by you. Cluster manager will take care of the resources based on the usage. If no job is running, then the worker resources will be free. Small portion of driver resources will be in use though.

Comment: Thanks.In subsequent use, I found that resources would be released without stop